# How to add parenthesis to queries in querydsl?

Tags: java, querydsl

I'm using `querydsl` for sql selects. Now I have native query that I want to transform to querydsl. It consists of two OR statements in parenthesis, followed by and AND query that applies thereby to both OR parts.

I need the following:

```
((q1 AND q2) OR (q3 AND q4)) AND q5
```

In querydsl I can write for example:

`BooleanExpression query = q1.and(q2).or(q3.and(q4)).and(q5)`

But that's not the same. What I really want is (note parenthesis):

`BooleanExpression query = ((q1.and(q2)).or((q3.and(q4))).and(q5)`

Question: how can I achieve this in java? How can I add those parenthesis logically to a querydsl expression.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let's assume we have three `BooleanExpression`s and we want to express `(q1 || q2) && q3`.

If you write `q1.or(q2).and(q3)`, than the `and` statement is the top level operand and `q1.or(q2)` is first evaluated and then used as the left-side of the expression. This is due to the fact that the operations are evaluated in the order they appear. Remember, this is Java syntax. Hence, it would be valid to use the statement.

However, if you do not like the notation, an alternative would be to simply write the following:

```
q3.and(q1.or(q2));
```

See [these examples](https://gist.github.com/timowest/5098112) for further information.

Comment: Ok so I simply can plain write that down without having to worry about parenthesis?

Comment: Yes, as explained and mentioned under the link, method chaining results in a tree like structure, where the most-right (not parenthesized) method-call is the tree root

Comment: This is correct. I think that all the confusion come from the fact that in SQL, AND have precedence over OR, but in QueryDsl, elements in the left are evaluated first

Answer (score 1):

use orAllOf , andAnyOf function

```
((q1 AND q2) OR (q3 AND q4)) AND q5
```

is

```
query.where( q5.orAllOf(andAnyOf(q1,q2), andAnyOf(q3,q4)) )
```